# Why does Zenity list kernels to remove, which it cannot find?

Tags: kernel, zenity

I am trying to use Zenity to remove old kernels (disk space issue), as described by WinEunuuchs2Unix on Mar 11, 2017 (and follow-ons).

Zenity lists kernels that it says can be removed. For example, one "pair"  of kernels is (with column headers that I assume are universal):

```
4.13.0-36-generic.efi.signed Feb 22 2018  7 MB     227 MB
4.13.0-36-generic            Feb 16 2018  77 MB    297 MB
```

When selecting OK, I am told that the files cannot be found, as shown in the pasted screen output below the sign-out. (I also get a `Gtk-Message` . . . and I have no idea what that is about.)

Indeed, nothing is found when using:

```bsh
sudo find / -name linux-image-4.13.0-36-generic.efi.signed
```

Why is Zenity listing kernels that are not there? Is there a way around it?

---

```
tscale:~$ sudo /usr/local/bin/rm-kernels 
Gtk-Message: 10:01:48.382: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
find: ‘/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-36*’: No such file or directory
find: ‘/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-36*’: No such file or directory
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-image-4.13.0-36-generic.efi.signed
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-image-4.13.0-36-generic.efi.signed'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-image-4.13.0-36-generic.efi.signed'
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.13.0-36
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-4.13.0-36'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-4.13.0-36'
E: Unable to locate package linux-image-4.13.0-36-generic
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-image-4.13.0-36-generic'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-image-4.13.0-36-generic'
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.13.0-36
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-4.13.0-36'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-4.13.0-36'
tscale:~$
```

Comment: Why do you not want to use mature `purge-old-kernels` script from `byobu` package?

Comment: N0rbert: Good question. I did try: "sudo purge-old-kernels"; to no avail. The response is:  Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.